# What is this message I heard in Subnautica about 9 new agents activated?

Tags: subnautica

I tried having the No Survival cheat and I used a cheat to cure myself but not the planet and I deactivated the gun before the Sunbeam arrived and then when the message for the Sunbeam was supposed to be played, all I got for a message was a creepy one: "9 new agent activated in hunting/analyzing mode sharing targets location now."

Does anyone know anything about that message because it gave me the creeps.  Can anyone try to figure out what it means? About ten minutes after the Sunbeam event was supposed to happen, I got the "too much debris" message.

Answer (score 3):

The message you heard was actually from a Warper, as [this](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Radio) wiki page says:

> The messages "▀▖┗▛Nine new biological subjects designated. Mode ▄▖▜▚┣: hunting/analyzing. Sharing subject locations with other agents." and "▀▖┗▛Subject 11783 destroyed. Mode ▄▖▜▚┣: patrol. New targets unaccounted for: 1." are broadcasted by Warpers.

This is also listed on the [Warpers](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Warper#Radio_Messages) wiki page.

What is suppose to happen when you deactivate the Quarantine Enforcement Platform prior to the Sunbeams arrival is the Sunbeam won't be able to land and rescue you due to a debris fields in orbit as you stated.  So I think you just coincidentally got this other radio message at a peculiar time.